# Android Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener not working

Tags: android, spinner

I have made a spinner dynamically during a login process.  I'd like to be able to return the value of the spinner when I click on an option but it doesn't seem to work.

I make the spinner here:

```
public Spinner page_spinner;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
...
page_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.page_spinner);
...
//MAKE ARRAY HERE
GraphRequest requestPage = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
    currentAccessToken,
    "/me/accounts",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject page = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String pageName = page.getString("name");
                if(!pageName.equals("")) {
                    //Push names into the array
                    pages_array.add(pageName);
                } else {
                    pages_array.clear();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
Bundle pageParameters = new Bundle();
pageParameters.putString("fields", "name,access_token,picture{url}");
requestPage.setParameters(pageParameters);
requestPage.executeAsync();
...
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StartPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pages_array);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
page_spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

then I try to use the spinner here:

```
page_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("***********", "THIS ");
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Log.d("***********", "THIS ");
    }
});
```

I don't ever get the `Log.d` or even if I made `Toast` there, it doesn't fire.  Not sure why this is stopping and I'm not getting any errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add your array initialization and generation code as well for sample

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, Added, but I'm editing down the comments and extranious code right now

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, I've culled the code so it's showing how I'm making the array

Comment: The code you show seems correct. Can you paste whole activity code.

Comment: Firstly comment pages_array.clear() as it might be possible some of the names are added and then pages_array is getting cleared. Secondly after your pages_array is fully populated or on adding of each new element you require to call  spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to reload spinner with new data.

Comment: You are not getting items in spinner, Am I right ?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, I am able to see all of the results inside of the spinner.  The array is working as expected and placing the names in the spinner and I am able to try to select them - It just does nothing when I actually do try to select one of them

Comment: @ChintanSoni, Please see comment above

Comment: yes still i suggest calling spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after your pages_array generation is complete.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, I've tried your comment as well and it has worked.  I had to declare the `spinnerArrayAdapter` as final, but as long as the `notifyDataSetChanged();` is under the try after the array is made, it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the spinner as a global variable and without `final`

and try this:

```
page_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.page_spinner);
...
//MAKE ARRAY HERE
GraphRequest requestPage = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
    currentAccessToken,
    "/me/accounts",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject page = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String pageName = page.getString("name");
                if(!pageName.equals("")) {
                    //Push names into the array
                    pages_array.add(pageName);
                } else {
                    pages_array.clear();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StartPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pages_array);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        page_spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this, but still nothing in the console

Comment: Build your spinner before the `Callback`  and set the adapter inside the `Callback` when your array is complete

Comment: Your comment did the trick - I've places the two lines starting with `ArrayAdapter<String>` and `spinnerArrayAdapter` in the `onComplete` of the `GraphRequest.Callback()`, just above the `try{` line.  Then I placed the `page_spinner` and `spinnerArrayAdapter` just under the last `catch`

Comment: If you wouldn't mind updating your answer to reflect the code, I could accept it as the answer

Comment: It will take 23 hours to be able to award a bounty.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your error seems somewhat correct. You are not notifying adapter about the changes in dataset.

Firstly, Your request is executed Async. So, your code execution will continue to next lines. So I guess, a blank array (size 0) is passed to `ArrayAdapter<>` and then the adapter is set to `Spinner` and then you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I think you should call `spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`as below:

```
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject page = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String pageName = page.getString("name");
                if(!pageName.equals("")) {
                    //Push names into the array
                    pages_array.add(pageName);
                } else {
                    pages_array.clear();
                }
            }
            spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, It will take 23 hours to award a bounty.  You do have more of an explanation, though the other three lines of code need to moved as well.  Just as Alberto's answer.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Not an issue. You clear with why you were committing the error, is more important. Bounty won't represent skills..:) Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your codes and everything seems Right here. First I tried Adding 10 Items at `spinner`. Everything worked fine. And I tested adding `List` of `String` which contains only one Item.

```
List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerArray.add("Item 1");
```

**My `OnItemSelectedListener`**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

But what happened is the code everything worked fine before was not working after because there is only one item in `spinnerArray`. `Toast` was shown when `Activity` loads and not called when `item` is selected. You may have the same issue there. So my suggestion is give priority to your `Array` which may contain only one `item`.